# How to enabIe incremental build mode for a new configuration for the Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, incremental-build

I'm working on an Angular project.
I try to define a new "development"-configuration  for the Angular CLI.
I already can do this:

```
ng serve -c=development
```

But it does always a complete build, when I change a piece of code.

When I use `ng serve` without the -c option with the very same project only a tiny build happens when I change something.
(Is the term "incremental build" the right one to describe this behavior?)

I want to have the CLI do this tiny build with "-c=development" too.

I tried to find it in the Angular documentation and with Google, but I can't figure it out.

My angular.json is (only the project name is altered):

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "MyProject": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "app",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "scss"
                }
            },
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/MyProject",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/assets/favicon.png",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                            "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
                            "src/styles.scss"
                        ],
                        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                            "includePaths": [
                                "src/assets/stylesheets"
                            ]
                        },
                        "scripts": [
                            "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                            "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
                            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                        ],
                        "es5BrowserSupport": true
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "development": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "test": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "stage": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.stage.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "MyProject:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "MyProject:build:production"
                        },
                        "development": {
                            "browserTarget": "MyProject:build:development"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "MyProject:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
                        "styles": [
                            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                            "src/styles.scss"
                        ],
                        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                            "includePaths": [
                                "src/assets/stylesheets"
                            ]
                        },
                        "scripts": [],
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                            "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "MyProject-e2e": {
            "root": "e2e/",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "",
            "architect": {
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "MyProject:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "MyProject:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "MyProject"
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Please be kind. The last time I've needed three or four edits before my question had all the information needed and had an appropriate style, though I always try to achieve this on the first attempt. Thank you!

UPDATE:

In guess-mode I've found a thing that makes the build way more faster than before. Not as fast as without the -c-Option, but it is a good start:

```
"configurations": {
    "development": {
        "optimization": false,
```

I set the optimization-property fo false.

But I would really appreciate further help, insides and improvements. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a satisfying solution.

The properties of a configuration-entry in configurations-section of angular.js are the same as the command line options for `ng build` (at least many of them). So in the documentation of ng build I've found what the default values are for different properties.

I've changed the following properties:

- "optimization": false
- "buildOptimizer": false,
- "aot": false,
- "outputHashing": "none",
- "namedChunks": true,
- "extractLicenses": false,

So my "development"-configuration-entry looks now like this:

```
                "configurations": {
                    "development": {
                        "fileReplacements": [
                            {
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                            }
                        ],
                        "optimization": false,
                        "outputHashing": "none",
                        "sourceMap": false,
                        "extractCss": true,
                        "namedChunks": true,
                        "aot": false,
                        "extractLicenses": false,
                        "vendorChunk": false,
                        "buildOptimizer": false,
                        "budgets": [
                            {
                                "type": "initial",
                                "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                "maximumError": "5mb"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
```

Now I get the same build times as without the -c-option.
Maybe there are more settings in the configuration that are not optimal for development, but for now, I'm happy with it.

Happy coding. Have fun!